# WindowsAzure.Storage package on telerik RadCloudUpload

Tags: telerik

We are planning to use RadCloudUpload control in asp.net webforms (.net framework 4.8) in order to upload the documents to blob storage directly. But internally it uses WindowsAzure.Storage package to upload the documents and now it is deprecated in NuGet package manager. Alternately  we have used Azure.Storage.Common /Azure.Storage.Blobs package but didn't help and RadCloudUpload control was looking for WindowsAzure.Storage package.

Could you please provide any solution towards it or it is fine to use depreciated WindowsAzure.Storage package on our end to make use of use RadCloudUpload control

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/cloudupload/cloud-storage-providers/azure-blob-storage

Comment: any answer? thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.